# Game shuts down when implementing the Font class

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

The following code causes my game to shut down. I do not know what is the problem with this code.

```
pygame.font.init()
font=pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Game Over", 1, (10, 10, 10))
background_image.blit(text, (0,0))
pygame.font.quit()
```

I want to display this text in the top left corner of the screen. Thanks.

Comment: nope, the screen just shuts down and IDLE tells you to restart

Comment: At a punt, I'll guess you're using Windows, and you're probably getting a segfault behind the scenes?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with the code in particular (i.e. logic problems, forgot to implement something...etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me -
I'd guess your platform  is not getting along quite well with the "None" font you are passing - try passing a complete path to a (in disk) font file (a TTF file) as the first parameter to `pygame.font.Font` -

Also, save your script and run it from the command shell to get hold of proper error messages.

Also, there is no need to call "pygame.font.quit" - just call "pygame.quit"  when exiting your program.